# Are these uniforms credible for American sailors just after WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, military, north-america, clothing, uniform

In the 1961 French film [Lola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lola_%281961_film%29) (set in the Atlantic French harbour [Nantes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nantes)), American soldiers wear the white uniforms seen below:

Was this uniform typical for these soldiers in Nantes following WW2?

Are these uniforms credible?
Or are they fabrications designed to produce a particular cinematographic effect? *(for instance giving an impression of light in the otherwise rather dark setting of the film)*
I am especially talking about the white color.

[image]
[image]

Comment: These are accurate. Other than hats and rank specialization, there weren't a lot of uniform changes between 1869 and 1973. See http://www.history.navy.mil/library/online/uniform_enlisted.htm.

Comment: Is there a reason you're suspicious?

Comment: That is what they wore.

Answer (score 2):

Looks not unreasonable to me.  Superficially, that looks like the US Naval Uniform, Summer white, enlisted.  I did a google search on that term. I'll admit that I was disappointed by the amount of noise in the results, but I found the following examples that are similar to the pictures you've cited.

- [Example 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=ww2%20naval%20uniforms&newwindow=1&safe=active&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS573US573&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=4jWwU8_kFZOTyAT2u4H4CQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=837#newwindow=1&q=ww2%20naval%20uniforms%20summer%20whites&safe=active&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=rB6WYuoWKPH5mM%253A%3B23WkGxUOzKenxM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fkhakiwhackydolls.files.wordpress.com%252F2012%252F05%252Funiform-2.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fkhakiwhackydolls.wordpress.com%252F%3B527%3B791)
- [Example 2: See #3](http://www.usww2uniforms.com/figures_navy.html)
- [Example 3](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fbluejacket.com%2Fusn%2Fimages%2Fsp%2Fbc%2Fbb4_iowa_1898-b.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fbluejacket.com%2Fsea-service_uniform_b.htm&h=349&w=400&tbnid=G0zaGTgaWSKhbM%3A&zoom=1&docid=7I3IsllzIJVc2M&ei=-jawU4WCJIqxyASCjYBY&tbm=isch&ved=0CFIQMyhKMEo4ZA&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=642&page=5&start=158&ndsp=42) - I was uncomfortable with the date, but I will accept @Oldcat's assurance that is is correct.
- [Example 4](http://www.georgefamily.net/HJLWWII.html)

I am puzzled by the lack of sleeve insignia. Today, I'd conclude that these men are E-1 (no insignia). I've actually never seen an E-1; they grow up so fast.

---

Comment: Battleships of the Iowa's class in WWII had three guns per turret.  The caption is probably accurate.

Comment: at http://www.pacificbattleship.com/page/news_photos there are pictures of the WWII Iowa's guns..as well as a sculpture reproducing my kissing picture!

Answer (score 0):

[image: VE DAY KISS]

This famous photo is known to have been to been taken on VE Day in New York.  Note the man in the rear in the identical sailor uniform, and the kisser is in a dark version of the same.

Comment: That puzzles me - there should never be a situation where winter and summer uniforms are worn at  the same time.  On the other hand the lack of any sleeve insignia on the kisser suggests that the uniform code at that time was different than it is now.

Comment: These are people from a number of places meeting in Times Square IIRC, in the Spring.  Different ships/bases might cut over at different times based on how hot it was expected to be.

Comment: From Mark Wallace's post Example 2, this might be a combination of undress whites and dress blue uniforms.